# Concatenate an echo statement having mysql_result

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the first name, last name and county to display but I am getting errors when I try to concatenate  the echo statement here. How can I correct this?

```
$query = mysql_query("
SELECT `first_name`, `last_name`,`county`
FROM  `contact`
WHERE `first_name` ='". mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name'])) ."'

");
  echo (mysql_num_rows($query) !== 0)? mysql_result($query,0,'first_name'):'Name not found';
?>
```

This is the message I receive:

> Warning: mysql_result(): last_name.county not found in MySQL result index 5 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax_Contact\name.php on line 14

Comment: "_I am getting errors_" Which errors, specifically?

Comment: Say... is `first_name`, `last_name` etc. supposed to be inside `backticks`? Unless there's something I haven't learned yet(?).

Comment: @Fred Yes, field names should be encapsulated in backticks. This helps MySQL distinguish between identifiers and reserved MySQL words. It is especially helpful if you have a field named `table` for example.

Comment: @SVM Please indicate which is line 14.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Thanks. I'm 2 days into learning SQL, but not a stranger to the Web (CGI/HTML/Design) *circa 1995*. I thought, and from what I read so far, is that backticks were for `reserved` words only. Unless I got it backwards.

Comment: it is the line with echo not as shown above but when I try to concatenate it using "."

Comment: @Fred They are, but unless you have memorized the [entire list of 263 reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), it is safer to backtick all field and table names.

Comment: @SVM The error is in the part that you didn't show. Will you show it as it exists in your real code?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Thanks again George, I'll surely read up on the link you gave me. I knew I should've stuck with **dBase IV**. Yeah, it's been a while, but my life took a right turn at => graphic arts way back when (1996). Cheers - *ok, back to the matter at hand*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should answer the OP's question in relation to his current code:

```
$query = mysql_query("
SELECT `first_name`, `last_name`,`county`
FROM  `contact`
WHERE `first_name` ='". mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name'])) ."'

");
  (mysql_num_rows($query) !== 0) ? print mysql_result($query,0,'first_name') : print 'Name not found';
?>
```

Also according to your error, make sure that this line:

```
`last_name`,`county`
```

is not currently

```
`last_name`.`county`
```

Notice the comma/period difference.

OR, if you are trying to display first name, last name, and county use this:

```
$query = mysql_query("
SELECT `first_name`, `last_name`,`county`
FROM  `contact`
WHERE `first_name` ='". mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name'])) ."'

");
  (mysql_num_rows($query) !== 0) ? print mysql_result($query,0,'first_name')." ".mysql_result($query,0,'last_name')." ".mysql_result($query,0,'county') : print 'Name not found';
?>
```

And ultimately for better performance and supported code use

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("your_host", "your_user", "your_password", "your_database");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "
SELECT `first_name`, `last_name`,`county`
FROM  `contact`
WHERE `first_name` ='". mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name'])) ."'

";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $rows[] = $row;
}

if($result->num_rows === 0){
    print 'Name not found';
}

foreach($rows as $row){
    print $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']." ".$row['county'];
}

/* free result set */
$result->close();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score -1):

Your easyest way is to use a newer version of the MySQL functions - mysqli is a very good one to go with. But if you have to rely on the old function set, then pleace read the documentation; mysql_result returns the data, and you should prepare it yourself in the code.
Also, I have to agree with @MarcB - use mysql_fetch_assoc or something like that when oyu are only and really expecting one single row.

But if you have the time, merge to the mysqli or PDO methods - they are more modern (in other words they are OOP all the way) and safer.

Answer (score -2):

First, don't use the mysql_*() library. It's deprecated and obsolete. But if you have to use it, then DON'T use mysql_result. It's inefficient. A better process is to fetch an entire row using the fetch functions

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($row);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {
  echo $row['first_name'], $row['last_name'], $row['county'];
}
```